# Is there some way to track when device is no longer used?

Tags: android, android-service

I'm trying to track event when device screen is turned off or hardware buttons (volume up/down) last used. Is there a way to track it using android services or something else?

Comment: Register BroadcastReceiver for `intent.action.SCREEN_OFF`, `intent.action.SCREEN_ON` to receive broadcasts for screen off and on events.